# How to automatically switch to another activity after animation ends

Tags: android, android-intent, android-animation

I am trying to do a splash screen in Android Studio. I have an image that I want to fade out (animation). Then, after the animation ends, I want the app to automatically switch to the Main Activity. With my current code, the Main Activity is displaying directly, without going through the animation first. And I don't understand why. I have updated the Android Manifest to specify that I want my Splash Activity to be launched. Still not working:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        fade();
    }

    public void fade() {
        ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
        logo.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1700);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

However, if I remove the last 2 lines (about the Intent), then my animation displays. So it's as if the Intent makes Android bypass my animation altogether.

Answer (score 0):

When you start an animation, that does not cause your code to stop until the animation completes.  Instead, each frame of the animation are scheduled over time.

animate() returns a [ViewPropertyAnimator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html), which you should use to register an [AnimatorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html) using [setListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#setListener(android.animation.Animator.AnimatorListener)).  When the listener triggers [onAnimationEnd()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.AnimatorListener.html#onAnimationEnd(android.animation.Animator)), then call startActivity to proceed.

```
logo.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1700).setListener(new AnimatorListener() {
    // implement all the method with empty bodies, but this one is important:
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just set an animation listener like this:

```
public void fade() {
    ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
    ViewPropertyAnimator anim = logo.animate();

    anim.setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    anim.alpha(0f).setDuration(1700).start();
}
```

However, note that it's frowned upon to make dedicated Splash activities like this.
For the "correct" way to do it, [see here....](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/)

Comment: @J.Tur What is the stack trace when it crashes?

Comment: 02-17 19:26:07.641 19467-19467/com.example.jean.splashtest3687 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.example.jean.splashtest3687, PID: 19467

Comment: @J.Tur  Need more than that.  Can you add your entire stack trace to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your **SplashActivity onCreate()** method :

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.logo);
logo.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1700);

new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable()
{ @Override
  public void run()
  {
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
      startActivity(intent);
  }
},2000) ;
```

This will show your animation and after 2 seconds, will navigate to the MainActivity.

Also, since the introduction of **MaterialTheme**, you can use the **Branded Launch Screen** instead of creating the SplashScreen. It is very simple to implement and you may refer to [this article by Antonio Leiva.](http://antonioleiva.com/branded-launch-screen)

Comment: Why do that when you can get a callback saying exactly when the animation completes?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your suggestion. However, it gives me a 2 compilation errors.

Comment: The line with Intent intent = new Intent  says it cannot resolve the constructor Intent in an anonymous method.

Comment: and the very last line, it says the semi-colon is not necessary but if I remove it, it says there should be a semi-colon

Answer (score 0):

```
ObjectAnimator fade = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(logo, View.ALPHA, 0);
fade.setDuration(1700);
fade.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {
    ...
    @Override 
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent); 
    }
    ...
});
```